# How to Set Up Nginx Permission In /root Directory?

Tags: permissions, python, nginx, flask

I Want To Deploy Flask Application On Ubuntu Server With Nginx And Gunicorn.
[I followed This Tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-serve-flask-applications-with-gunicorn-and-nginx-on-ubuntu-18-04).

1).So Every Thing Is Good Up To Gunicorn Configuration.
2). I Creates /etc/systemd/system/myproject.service . It Look Like

```
[Unit]
Description=Gunicorn instance to serve myproject
After=network.target

[Service]
User=root
Group=www-data
WorkingDirectory=/root/myproject
Environment="PATH=/root/myproject/myprojectenv/bin"
ExecStart=/root/myproject/myprojectenv/bin/gunicorn --workers 3 --bind unix:myproject.sock -m 007 wsgi:app

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

3). After Starting myproject.service it will create myproject.sock file in my project folder which is in */root* path and This File has permission **srwxrwx---**.

4). My **/etc/nginx/sites-available/myproject** File Look Like

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name your_domain www.your_domain;

    location / {
        include proxy_params;
        proxy_pass http://unix:/root/myproject/myproject.sock;
    }
}
```

5). After Restarting Nginx it Showing 403 Forbidden error On Browser.

6). Nginx Log File Look Like [See Log File](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q0vIl.png) Showing While Connecting To Upstream Permission Denied.
7). **When I Am Generating .sock File in /tmp folder It Is Working.....**
but I Want To Generate It In /root directory

So Can Anyone Help Me In This Issue Or Share Linux Permission Related Tutorials etc.(Thanks In Advance....)

Comment: Why do you want to run it as root, and have it in `/root`? The tutorial you claim to have followed explicitly calls for non-root-user.

Comment: I Have Only One User Called Root User....    And I My Project Directory Is In /root Path.... So Can You Suggest Me Where Should I Keep My Project Or In Which Directory And Which User Or I Have To Create New User. So Nginx Can Have All The Permission In That Directory And For That User....

Answer (score 0):

For a start it is a huge risk to run a server as root, better you create another system-user for your project using `useradd -r -U -s /usr/bin/nologin http`. This creates a new system-user called http and creates a http group.

You can then use `chown -R :http /root/myproject/` to change the owning group to http.

If your nginx.conf contains the statement `user http;` you should be able to access the socket now.

Additionally I'd recommend creating and using a normal user account. If you need root access you can use su or sudo to execute as such.

Comment: `www-data` is the default user NGINX uses, and it's been that way since 12.04.